# PTIJ: Why Didn't Jacob Shave His Beard

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The verse states (Gen 48:10) ועיני ישראל כבדו מזקן לא יוכל לראות "And Israel's eyes were weakened (i.e. obstructed) by his beard, so he couldn't see". If his beard was obstructing his vision, why didn't he just shave?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Shave??!!! OSSUURR!!!!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yaakov followed the rule of שב ואל תעשה עדיף - ***Shave*** Ve'Al Taaseh Adif

Answer (score 6):

Actually the word כבדו comes from the word כבד meaning "honor". So his eyes were actually honored by his having the beard. If he shaved it, his eyes wouldn't be honored!